# Remove received push notifications after 5 seconds automatically for my app

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

In my application, My device is getting received Push notifications. If the user will not open received push notification for 5 secs or 10 secs, need to cancel or remove that particular push notification. How can we imlement this in the iOS application

Please Advice.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot programmatically remove the visual display of a push notification. If the user has i. e. set your app to display push notifications on the lock screen they will disappear when the user selects them.

If the text message in your notifications is not important you can for example play a custom sound file that's bundled with your app.